# is there a good general policy for setting up the sequence of catch blocks?

Tags: programming-languages

is there a good general policy for setting up the sequence of catch blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would catch the most "specific" exception first, then further down catch the more general ones:

```
try {
  ...
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex) {
 ...
}
catch (InvalidArgumentException ex) {
  ...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Technically yes, but there would not be a relevant performance hit. I wouldn't worry about this though, since optimizing error scenarios hardly seems worth the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014(VS.80).aspx) from MSDN.  It might also be good to check out the Enterprise Library [exception handling block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203116.aspx).  Lots of good stuff there for architecting an exception handling strategy.